# get text beetwen character in Java, regex

Tags: java, regex, string

I want get text beetwen tag `"<p>"` and `"</p>"`
for example i have:
`String stringText = "<html><head></head><body><p>Aa , aa.</p><p><b>Aa aa, aa.</b></p><p>Aa aa aa, aa.</p><p><i>Aa, aa.</i></p><p><b><i>B, b, b.</i></b></p><b>Aa aa, aa.</b></body></html>";`
and i want get only this:

```
"Aa aa Aa aa aa Aa aa aa aa Aa aa B b b "
```

Without coma and dot.And i want that every word was alone in an array of String, because next i must count every word;

Also i find some example but i don't know what i have to write into Pattern.compile

```
private static final Pattern TAG_REGEX = Pattern.compile("<p>(.+?)</p>");
private static List<String> getTagValues(final String str) {
    final List<String> tagValues = new ArrayList<String>();
    final Matcher matcher = TAG_REGEX.matcher(str);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        tagValues.add(matcher.group(1));
    }
    return tagValues;
}
```

and in my program:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getTagValues(stringText).toArray()));
```

But it doesn't work correctly, anyone know what i have to write in `Pattern.compile("");` ? 
now I get this:

```
[Aa, aa., <b>Aa aa, aa.</b></p><p>Aa aa aa, aa., <i>Aa, aa.</i></p><p><b><i>B, b, b.</i></b></p><b>Aa aa, aa.</b><p>]
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for letting us know. Have you tried anything? What's your question? Where is your code?

Comment: a little tip is to use regex. i am kind enough to provide you the regex for java, but the rest of the code is your job. `\\<\\w+\\>|\\<\\/\\w+\\>` is the regex you would need to simplify your problem

Comment: I edited my post, and add some code

Answer (score 0):

Since you tried something, we can finally help you. The first thing i do, is to remove all the existing tags aka every `<xyz>`. Then you only have the text left you want to count. Next step is to have a proper split operator. I chose to have commas and dots as point to split. I know its not the best way, like i did it, but i couldn't come up with a good regex to replace every space and dot which are needed with a comma. The string looks like this after removing the tags:
 `Aa , aa.Aa aa, aa.Aa aa aa, aa.Aa, aa.B, b, b.Aa aa, aa.`
And after replacing some spaces with commas it looks like this:
`Aa,,,aa.Aa,aa,,aa.Aa,aa,aa,,aa.Aa,,aa.B,,b,,b.Aa,aa,,aa.`
Now we split the `String` at every comma and dot. Since we have places, where several commas come after one another, we have empty entries in the array. While counting, we ignore the empty entries with the if. The `.trim()` is to make sure, there are no entries with a space in it which could distort the result.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String stringText = "<html><head></head><body><p>Aa , aa.</p><p><b>Aa aa, aa.</b></p><p>Aa aa aa, aa.</p><p><i>Aa, aa.</i></p><p><b><i>B, b, b.</i></b></p><b>Aa aa, aa.</b></body></html>";
    stringText = stringText.replaceAll("\\<\\w+\\>|\\<\\/\\w+\\>", "");
    stringText = stringText.replaceAll(" ", ",");
    String[] h = stringText.split(",|\\.");
    int counter = 0;
    for (String str : h) {
        if (!str.trim().isEmpty()) {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(counter);

}
```

Comment: thanks for your comment, but I update my post and output, i made mistake my output should be: `Aa aa Aa aa aa Aa aa aa aa Aa aa B b b`, you know what i must edit in your code? It must only take the text between <p> </p> and ignore <b> </b> and the like, so text beetween <b> </b> without before <p> i must ignore

Comment: i really don't understand which to ignore and which not. as you said, only the text, which is directly enclosed by <p> and </p> should be taken. therefore the right output would be `Aa aa Aa aa aa aa Aa aa` the rest of the text is enclosed by either `<b><i></i></b>` or by `<b></b>`

Comment: from: `<p>Aa , aa.</p>` should be `Aa aa` from: `<p><b>Aa aa, aa.</b></p>` should be `Aa aa aa` from: `<p>Aa aa aa, aa.</p>` should be: `Aa aa aa aa` from: `<p><i>Aa, aa.</i></p>` should be : `Aa aa` from: `<p><b><i>B, b, b.</i></b></p>` should be : `B b b` from: `<b>Aa aa, aa.</b>` should be nothing since we ignore it because we havn'e <p> </p> beetwen this text. I want only this text beetwen <p> and </p> and this text should be without any <i>, <b> or sometnig else